# Match dot files recursively using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match any dot file in a path recursively. I started with:

```
^[.]
```

But this does not match the case of `long/path/here/.dotfile`. Also it matches `.` by itself, which is incorrect. The regular expression should match `.` and then require at least one character after.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be captured in the example of `long/path/here/.dotfile`?

Comment: What if you just used "starts with" function and filtered "." when you found it?

Comment: What tool (and what language?) you used to do the regex match?

Comment: @m_callens just a full match of that path, because it includes a `.` file.

Comment: @squiguy this is being passed into a command line tool as an argument, so I am guessing PCRE?

Comment: @Justin if you just want to find all files start with dot recursively, you probably don't need regex: `find /path/to/lookup -type f -name '.*'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^\/?(?:\w+\/)*(\.\w+)`

`^` - signifies the beginning of the string
`\/?` - possibility of preceeding `/`
`(?:\w+\/)*` - non-capture group to find 0-inf matches of sub directory paths (e.g. `long/path/.../`)
`(\.\w+)` - capture group to get the any file at the end of a path beginning with `.`

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/kR47TC/2)

Comment: Very close, but does not handle the case of `/long/path/.dotfile`.

Comment: @Justin fixed it!

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

the way i can think are 2 regular expressions

1. `^[\.]` matches anything in the root directory that doesn't start with a `.`
2. `(?<=\/)\.` matches any subdirectory that matches a `/` followed by a `.`.

test cases:

```
.foo
foo.a
/a/.foo
/a/foo.a
/.foo/.asdafsdf
```

Answer (score 0):

In @m_callens answer, path with space or dash or non-English character will fail.

`^\/?(?:[^/]+\/)*(\.[^/]+)$`

- `^` - match the start
- `\/?` - 0 or 1 `/`
- `(?:[^/]+\/)*`

  - `*` - 0 or more
  - `(?:)` - non-capture group
  - `[^/]+\/` - 1 or more not `/` , with a `/` at the end
- `(\.[^/]+)` - capture group, 1 or more not `/` , with a `.` at the start
- `$` - match the end

you can test this regexp [here](https://regexr.com/685l6) with

`/home/ddddd/hhhhh/gfg-u556u asdf 雪 、\ asdf \ asdf/demo-project/demo- —— _ (1)-project new copy /src/imgs/ツ/.DS_Store`